# SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'mkstudent.classes_student' doesn't exist (SQL: insert into `classes_student` (`classes_id`,

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

i dont know why it is going to store in mkstudent.classes_student table , i mean i created many to many table class_student and when i tray to store a a student that have a class this error is happening any one who can help me please?
the code is here
student controller

```
public function store(createstudentrequest $request)
    {

       $student= Student::create([
            'first_name'=>$request->first_name,
            'last_name'=>$request->last_name,
            'phone_number'=>$request->phone_number
        ]);

        if($request->class){
            $student->classe()->attach($request->class);
        }

        session()->flash('success','student added successfully');
        return redirect(route('students.index'));
    }
```

student.create

```
<form action="{{route('students.store')}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
            @csrf
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="title">First Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="first_name" class="form-control" value="">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="title">Last Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="last_name" class="form-control" value="">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="title">Phone Number</label>
                <input type="text" name="phone_number" class="form-control" value="">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Class">Class</label>
                @if($classes->count() > 0)
                <select name="class[]" id="class" multiple="true" class="form-control">
                    @foreach($classes as $class)
                    <option value="{{$class->id}}">
                        {{$class->name}}
                    </option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
                @endif
            </div>
```

and the migration for class_student is

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('class_student', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->integer('classes_id');
            $table->integer('student_id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

and in the student model

```
class Student extends Model
{
     protected $fillable = [
        'first_name','last_name','phone_number'
    ];

    public function classe()
    {
      return $this->belongsToMany(Classes::class);
    }
}
```

in the classes model

```
 public function students()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Student::class);
    }
```

Comment: You need to mention the table name on your relation `return $this->belongsToMany(Classes::class, 'class_student');` and `return $this->belongsToMany(Student::class, 'class_student');`

Comment: it works tank you so much ......and when i tray to get the name of the class that the student is registered in this way ```{{$student->classe['name']}}``` it says Undefined index: name (View: C:\Users\user\Desktop\mkstudent\resources\views\students\index.blade.php) how can i handled it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass table name as second parameter in 'classe' relation like this:

```
public function classe()
    {
      return $this->belongsToMany(Classes::class, 'class_student');
    }
```

Comment: it worked tank you .......and when i tray to get the name of the class that the student is registered in this way {{$student->classe['name']}} it says Undefined index: name (View: C:\Users\user\Desktop\mkstudent\resources\views\students\index.blade.php) how can i handled it?

Comment: use {{$student->classe->first()->name}} it retrieve first record, moreover for retrieve all records you can use 'foreach' on $student->classe

Comment: tank you ...it works in  {{$student->classe->first()['name']}} and it display only the first class and what if the student is registered in multiple class and want to display all the class he is registered ??

Comment: you can use foreach , @foreach($student->classe as $classe) {{$classe->name}} @endforeach

Comment: if my answer helped you mark my answer as the best

Answer (score 0):

In relations (in both models) as second parameter you must provide table name `class_student` because you don't follow convention because you model name is `Classes`

Comment: it worked tank you .......and when i tray to get the name of the class that the student is registered in this way {{$student->classe['name']}} it says Undefined index: name (View: C:\Users\user\Desktop\mkstudent\resources\views\students\index.blade.php) how can i handled it?

Comment: you must foreach $student->classes because it's collection

Comment: Can you mark my answer as the best one or at least valuable? ;)

Comment: Can you at least vote for my answer as valuable because you remove best answer flag?